# How to group marker using Cluster in Google Map in Swift?

Tags: swift, google-maps

I build my application have google map function. How can i group the marker (you can see the image) by using cluster. Anyone please show me how to do it? Thank a lot

[image: my marker]

[image]

Comment: Check belove code may it help you. Thanks.

Comment: your solution is only zoom out the camera, it is not cluster. Anyway, thanks for you comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to initialize a cluster manager object as follows, this will call from `viewDidLoad` method.

```
// MARK: INITIALIZE CLUSTER ITEMS
func initializeClusterItems() {
    let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()
    let algorithm = GMUGridBasedClusterAlgorithm()
    let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: mapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
    self.clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: mapView, algorithm: algorithm, renderer: renderer)
    self.clusterManager.cluster()
    self.clusterManager.setDelegate(self as GMUClusterManagerDelegate, mapDelegate: self)
}
```

**then updating your code**

```
func setMarkerForMap(locations: [LocationNearBy]) -> Void {

    let imgTypeDoctor = UIImage(named: "map_icon_doctor")
    let imgTypeHospital = UIImage(named: "map_icon_hospital")
    let imgTypeDrugstore = UIImage(named: "map_icon_medicin")

    //clear all marker before load again
    self.mapView.clear()
    var index = 0
    for location in locations {

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(location.lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(location.long))
        marker.position = coordinate

        //set image
        if (location.locationTypeID == 1) {
            marker.icon = imgTypeDoctor
        } else if (location.locationTypeID == 2 || location.locationTypeID == 3 || location.locationTypeID == 4) {
            marker.icon = imgTypeHospital
        } else if (location.locationTypeID == 5) {
            marker.icon = imgTypeDrugstore
        }

        marker.userData = location
        marker.map = mapView
        mapView.delegate = self
        self.generatePOIItems(String(format: "%d", markerIndex), position: coordinate, icon: marker.icon)
       index += 1
    }
    self.clusterManager.cluster()
}
```

then we have to assign markers to `clusterManager` object

```
// MARK: ADD MARKER TO CLUSTER
func generatePOIItems(_ accessibilityLabel: String, position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, icon: UIImage?) {
    guard let item = POIItem(position: position, name: accessibilityLabel, icon: icon) else {
        return
    }
    self.clusterManager.add(item)
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You need to add 'GoogleMapCluster' files to your project

Comment: Thank a lot for your perfect answer. But i got the error with "POIItem". How can i fix this ?

Comment: yes will checking lib link for you and then will post.

Comment: Your mind is pod 'GoogleMapCluster' or import 'GoogleMapCluster' ??? Sorry because the first time i'm using google map

Comment: you can use this https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils and for pod installation follow https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/setup

Comment: hi PiyushRathi, thanks you so much for your helping. i did it already, but the problem is my image marker (the blue one, you can see on the image) change to the red pin. So how can i fix this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178167/discussion-between-trung-nguyen-and-piyushrathi).

Answer (score 1):

```
 func setMarkerForMap(locations: [LocationNearBy]) -> Void {

        //clear all marker before load again
        self.mapView.clear()

        let location = locations[0]
        let update = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(location.lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(location.long)), zoom: 10)

        for location in locations {

            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(location.lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(location.long))

            //set image
            if (location.locationTypeID == 1) {
                marker.icon = UIImage(named: "map_icon_doctor")
            } else if (location.locationTypeID == 2 || location.locationTypeID == 3 || location.locationTypeID == 4) {
                marker.icon = UIImage(named: "map_icon_hospital")
            } else if (location.locationTypeID == 5) {
                marker.icon = UIImage(named: "map_icon_medicin")
            }

            marker.userData = location
            marker.map = mapView
            marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true
            mapView.delegate = self
        }
        mapView.animate(with: update)
    }
```

Comment: your solution is only zoom out the camera, it is not cluster. Anyway, thanks for you comment

Answer (score 0):

```
class POIItem: NSObject, GMUClusterItem {
var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var name: String!
var icon: UIImage

  init(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String, icon: UIImage) {
    self.position = position
    self.name = name
    self.icon = icon
  }
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
//MARK:- Variable 
private var clusterManager: GMUClusterManager!

override func viewDidLoad(){
let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()
let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: self.mapView ?? GMSMapView(),clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
renderer.delegate = self
self.clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: self.mapView ?? GMSMapView(), algorithm: algorithm,
                                                    renderer: renderer)


self.clusterManager.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)
// Call cluster() after items have been added to perform the clustering and rendering on map.
self.clusterManager.cluster()

for i in 0..<self.model.count{
     //if you want to rescale image of marker. function used imageWithImage()           
     let img = self.imageWithImage(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imgMarker"), scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 60, height: 35))

  // Generate and add random items to the cluster manager.
     self.generateClusterItems(lat: self.model[i].lat ?? "", lng: self.model[i].long ?? "", name: "\(i)", icon: img)
   }
}

/// Randomly generates cluster items within some extent of the camera and
/// adds them to the cluster manager.
private func generateClusterItems(lat: String, lng: String,name: String, icon: UIImage) {
    let lat = JSON(lat).doubleValue
    let lng = JSON(lng).doubleValue
    let item =
        POIItem(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng), name: name, icon: icon)

    clusterManager.add(item)
}

///function to make image rescaled
func imageWithImage(image:UIImage, scaledToSize newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
  }
}

 //MARK:- GMUClusterManagerDelegate-
extension HomeViewController: GMUClusterManagerDelegate {
func clusterManager(_ clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTap clusterItem: GMUClusterItem) -> Bool {
    print("didTap clusterItem")    
    return true
}

func clusterManager(_ clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTap cluster: GMUCluster) -> Bool {
    print("didTap cluster")
    return true
 }
}
```